# Problem to see Web Services running on local machine

Tags: c#, web-services, visual-studio-2005

I have written some web service, I run it and see it from my firefox and run it from there.

Now I want to call it from some other code/solution i trying to add there a web reference and Web Services on the Local Machine , but i cannot see there my web services.

Any idea what is missing ? Sorry for the newbie question it's my first time with web services.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have it hosted? what type of web service is it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you run the `web service` you will get a url in browser.Copy that, in reference of your project A`dd Webreference` , it will ask for the url paste it and click go.Add that to your project.

If you are not added in `IIS`. please add it to IIS and do the rest of operation.other wise when you try for that you wont get the web service. 
`Or` run web service in visual studio debugger and dont close and to the operations.

please also ref: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d9w023sx(VS.80).aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you created the Web service project in a file system, then it ll automatically assign the temporary port number to run the service. In this case you cannot see the service in other projects.

Try creating the IIS virtual directory for the web service and see.